# jQuery not working with Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

My jquery.js works for using JavaScript, but not jQuery. The jQuery file does not work.

Below is my app.js

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname +'/views/index.html');
})

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.send('this is the about page');
})

app.get('/roster', function(req, res){
  res.send('this is the roster page');
})

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  res.send('this is the conact page');
})


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000);
```

below is my index.html

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<p>hi<p>
<h1><a href="/contact">contact</a></h1>

<body>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
</body>
```

And last below is my jQuery.js. I know everything is routed correctly as I ran an alert JavaScript and it worked correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
   $('div').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=10px'
       });
   });
   $('div').click(function() {
       $(this).toggle(1000);
   });
});
```

Comment: This is a community website not commercial. Don't offer money.

Comment: *"Anyone who helps me solve this I will venmo you $5"* - So you're ready to pay out $1000 if two-hundred people answer? Anyway, you don't seem to have included the jQuery library on your page.

Comment: There is another library for using jQuery in express. Refer here https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: "The jquery file does not work." is NOT a good question here on stack overflow.  Please explain what the expected behavior is, what the observed behavior is and what the exact problem that you want help with is.  Also, explain what debugging steps you've taken yourself and what you learned from those.  Also, we need to know what errors show in the browser console.

Comment: I apologize for the $5 offering.  I will make sure my next question posted here will be more professional.  Btw what do you mean by add the JQuery library to express?  Do you mean just to include <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>?  Either way Alexander Higgins helped me out below.  Did not imagine that people answered this fast on stackoverflow.  Again I will ask future questions with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding jQuery to your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After fixing your HTML (Your elements should all be inside the `<body>` and fixing you animation targets it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).animate({
      height: 60
    });
  });
  $('div').mouseleave(function() {
    var h = ($(this).height() + '').replace('px', '');
    var hto = Number(h) - 10;
    $(this).animate({
      height: 20
    });
  });
  $('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

#yellow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}

#green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="html">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>


<body>

  <p>hi</p>
      <h1><a href="/contact">contact</a></h1>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="blue"></div>
      <div id="yellow"></div>
      <div id="green"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  If you want the $5 let me know.  Either way huge help.  So the reason it wasn't working I assume was because of not having the html header correctly and forgetting this ? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, you didn't have jQuery and that tag loads it. And I don't want your money. What you can do is read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and take some time to get familiar with how things work on this site.

Comment: when i install jquery localy in directory it wont work, strange dont know why

Answer (score 1):

Check Whether you have added a static File path connecting the jquery file to the main javascript file. It might work.

--install bower globally

--and then, bower install jquery

--add a script tag connecting the file to the HTML/pug file, script(src='/js/main.js')

then--in the main js file,
                 app.use(express.static('/public'));

Answer (score 0):

Probably because jQuery isn't bound to dynamic elements.
Consider using a parent selector of a static element.

```
$('body').on("click", "red", func(e){

//do something 

});
```

Etc etc etc

This is obviously all contingent upon jQuery being loaded.

Also, your HTML is malformed. No HTML should reside between `</head>` and `<body>`

Also, consider invoking your libraries before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('./public'));

// use static middleware before all your routes


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname +'/views/index.html');
})

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.send('this is the about page');
})

app.get('/roster', function(req, res){
  res.send('this is the roster page');
})

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  res.send('this is the conact page');
})
```